# A few AvalonDock styling questions (WPF)

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, avalondock

I'm trying to implement AvalonDock into my application, but I'm having trouble figuring out some of the styling techniques. If someone could please help with the following couple of questions, I would be very grateful:

1) Is there a way to remove the main "Close" button from a DocumentPane and instead place individual buttons on the tabs?

2) I have custom-styled buttons in my application that are placed inside DockableContent elements. As long as the DockableContent is docked, the button uses my custom template, but if a pull the DockablePane that contains the DockableContent out and have it floating, the button loses its template. Is there some trick to getting this to hold?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the best luck getting around this by just downloading the source code, making my changes, and recompiling the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to #2, that seems to be a problem in AvalonDock. I have a TabControl that loses its styling when its dockable content is floated. When docked, styling is restored.

The workaround is to reset the styling on the StateChanged event.

```
private void OnDockableContentStateChanged (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (uxDockableContent.State == DockableContentState.DockableWindow)
    {
        foreach (TabItem tabItem in uxTabControl.Items)
        {
            tabItem.Style = FindResource ("TabItemStyle") as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that if you style the element itself everything is fine. The bug only appears to occur if you style it in the Window.Resources and then reference it on the element itself.